# Filter is returning all children for parent with matching child

Tags: swift, realm, filtering, nspredicate

I'm using Realm for Swift and I have a structure as follows:

```
class Navigation: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    dynamic var title: String?
    let companies = List<Companies>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}

class Companies: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    dynamic var name: String?
    let locations = List<Locations>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}

class Locations: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    ...
    dynamic var zip: String?
    let contacts = List<Contacts>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}

class Contacts: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    dynamic var firstName: String?
    dynamic var lastName: String?
    ...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to filter out locations by zip code, so that only locations that match the given zip code are displayed. I'm doing that like this

```
companies = realm.objects(Navigation.self).filter("key = 4").first!.companies.filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "key")
```

The `key = 4` bit is because the filter is only supposed to search in companies under one specific category.

The problem that I'm having is that it returns all locations for a company that has a matching location. So if my zip to find is 12345, and companyA has a location that matches, all the locations under companyA are returned, even if they aren't a match.

How can I limit the results to be **only** locations with a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I limit the results to be **only** locations with a match?

Right now you're returning a `Results<Companies>`, but it seems like you want locations. I accomplished what I think you're looking for by adding some inverse relationship properties to the `Companies` and `Locations` models, and then queried the Realm for `Locations` matching `zip == '12345' && ANY parentCompanies.parentNavigation.key == 4`.

Here's a sample app that demonstrates this:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Navigation: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    dynamic var title: String?
    let companies = List<Companies>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}

class Companies: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    dynamic var name: String?
    let locations = List<Locations>()
    let parentNavigation = LinkingObjects(fromType: Navigation.self, property: "companies")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}

class Locations: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    // ...
    dynamic var zip: String?
    let contacts = List<Contacts>()
    let parentCompanies = LinkingObjects(fromType: Companies.self, property: "locations")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}

class Contacts: Object {

    dynamic var key = 0
    dynamic var firstName: String?
    dynamic var lastName: String?
    // ...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
        let realm = try! Realm()

        // Objects Matching Query
        try! realm.write {
            // Locations
            let locations = Locations()
            locations.zip = "12345"

            // Companies
            let companies = Companies()
            companies.name = "Companies A"
            companies.locations.append(locations)

            // Nav
            let nav = Navigation()
            nav.key = 4
            nav.companies.append(companies)

            // Add to Realm
            realm.add(nav)
        }

        let locationsIn12345AndNavigationKey4 = realm.objects(Locations.self)
            .filter("zip == '12345' && ANY parentCompanies.parentNavigation.key == 4")
        print(locationsIn12345AndNavigationKey4)

        return true
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Results<Locations> (
  [0] Locations {
    key = 0;
    zip = 12345;
    contacts = RLMArray <0x6000000f2100> (

    );
  }
)
```

Comment: I could work with this, but ideally I would like it to also have the companies that "own" the locations, so that the user knows what company they're looking at. There are a lot of locations named similarly, like "Main Office".

Comment: Easy: `locationsIn12345AndNavigationKey4.flatMap { $0.parentCompanies }`

Comment: Could you make this more code friendly? Is this supposed to be the string that goes into the filter are these actual function calls? I assume this would also have to be done with the inverse relationships?

Comment: I don't understand any of those questions. Could you please rephrase?

Comment: The comment you made, `locationsIn12345AndNavigationKey4.flatMap { $0.parentCompanies }`, is this supposed to go into the `filter()` function as a string, or is it code? If so, what do I append it to?

Comment: You could write that immediately after the `print` statement in my code above to derive the parent companies of the locations obtained.

Comment: Very nice @jpsim

Comment: @jpsim This has been very helpful, but I was wondering if you could help me with something with this. I used the `locationsIn12345AndNavigationKey4.flatMap { $0.parentCompanies }` tip you gave me, but I don't know how to work with the object type returned, `LazyCollection<FlattenBidirectionalCollection<LazyMapBidirectionalCollection<Results<Locations>, LinkingObjects<Companies>>>>`. The data type I've been using is `Results<Companies>`, is there a way to get the result from your suggestion to match up at all? Thanks.